# Is it possible to use AutoHotKey to run PSLoggedOn and edit the output in the stream and return the result?

Tags: windows, autohotkey, sysinternals

I am using AutoHotKey to build a simple GUI tool that uses the Sysinternals tool PSLoggedOn. First if I use
`run psloggedon.exe -l -x \\computername` I don't get any output at all.

So I tried `run %ComSpec% /C psloggedon.exe -l -x 1> %Temp%\psloggedon.txt` and that gives me the output in domain\username format for each user logged in.

Like my first example I would rather just run psloggedon and get the output instead of first opening a command prompt; is that possible somehow?

Either way I want to take the output and avoid writing it to a file, but instead edit the output from the output stream to remove the "domain\" part and then just return the username. How can this be done without any third-party software?

Comment: It's pretty complicated to do, but there is a way.  Are you sure you don't want to read the file, change the text, and overwrite/delete the file?  10x easier.

Comment: Well, if it is that much more complicated then maybe I will just do that. It seems odd that writing it to a file, then modifying it, and reading it would be the complicated way to do it. Maybe I'm just used to programming languages where assigning the value to a variable and modifying that would be the easy way.

Comment: Could you post the data from the file?  If you know other languages, check out [StringGetPos](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringGetPos.htm) and [StringSplit](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringSplit.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://serverfault.com/a/203890) answer to another question on Serverfault shows a way to do it by reading the StdoutRead.
I too was looking at a way to avoid using a file but have decided it's actually the simplest option.

Code copied from user60738

```
#include <Constants.au3>
Dim $line, $line2, $file, $icount, $reg, $reg2, $reg3
$file = FileOpen("pclist.txt", 0)
While 1
    $line = FileReadLine($file)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    $reg3 = ""
    $reg2 = ""
    $reg = ""
    If Ping($line, 200) Then
        $reg = @ComSpec & ' /C "' & @ScriptDir & "\pstools\psloggedon.exe -l -x \\" & $line & '"'
        $reg = Run($reg, "", @SW_HIDE, $STDOUT_CHILD + $STDERR_CHILD)
        While 1
            $reg2 = StdoutRead($reg)
            If @error Then ExitLoop
            If $reg2 Then
                $reg3 &= $reg2
            EndIf
        WEnd
        If StringInStr($reg3, "Error") Then
            $reg = "Error"
        ElseIf StringInStr($reg3,"No one is logged") Then
                $reg = "No one is logged on locally."
        Else
                $reg = StringTrimLeft($reg3, StringInStr($reg3, Chr(13), "", 3))
                $reg = StringTrimLeft($reg, StringInStr($reg, "\"))
                $reg = StringTrimRight($reg, StringLen($reg) - StringInStr($reg, Chr(13)))
                $reg = StringStripWS($reg, 8)
        EndIf
        $icount += 1
        $line2 &= $icount & @TAB & $line & @TAB & $reg & @CRLF
    EndIf
    TrayTip("Psloggedon", $icount & " " & $line & " User: " & $reg, 10)
WEnd
FileClose($file)
ConsoleWrite($line2)
FileDelete("C:\output.txt")
FileWrite("C:\output.txt", $line2)
ShellExecute("C:\output.txt")
```